# WSO2 ESB blocking call timeout

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 for backend service invocation using blocking call. I have to use blocking call because of jms transaction. Sometimes the network between ESB and backend service is slow so I want to use timeout on connection, but with blocking call timeout on endpoint doesn't work. With non-blocking call timeout works fine.

Is it possible to use timeout with blocking call?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

As endpoint timeout not working in blocking call you can try out following two methods:

1) Global timeout defined in synapse.properties(ESB_HOME\repository\conf) file. 
This will decide the maximum time that a callback is waiting in the ESB for a response for a particular request.

If ESB does not get any response from Back End, it will drop the message and clears out the call back. This is a global level parameter which affects all the endpoints configured in ESB.

```
synapse.global_timeout_interval=120000
```

2) Socket timeout defined in the passthru-http.properties (ESB_HOME\repository\conf) file.

This parameter will decide on the timeout which a particular http request is waiting for a response. If ESB does not receive any response from the Back End during this period, HTTP connection get timed out and that will eventually throws timeout error in the ESB side and fault handlers will be hit.

```
http.socket.timeout=60000
```

Comment: `synapse.global_timeout_interval` isn't working with blocking call either.
`http.socket.timeout` works but very strange. If the network connection is slow and it's taking longer than `http.socket.timeout` to send request, `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` is thrown right after the server receive requet. So if 100KB request is send with speed 1KB/s, it would take 100 seconds and SocketTimeoutException is thrown after 100 seconds, even if the http.socket.timeout value is lower .

Answer (score 0):

We can define blocking timeout at /repository/conf/axis2/**axis2_blocking_client.xml** by defining **SO_TIMEOUT** parameter for relevant TransportSender [1].

[1] - https://medium.com/@dilsimchandrasena/set-timeout-for-endpoints-when-call-mediator-blocking-true-fd2744b2cc19